# array sort, how to change key 1 for key 2 in an entire array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

so what i have is an array like this one:

```
//        user 1 $historia[id_usuario][id_historia]
    $historia[1][1] = '1asdfasf';
    $historia[1][8] = '1asdfasf';
    $historia[1][7] = '1asdfasf';
    $historia[1][4] = '1asdfasf';

//        user 2 $historia[id_usuario][id_historia]
    $historia[2][5] = '2asdfasf';
    $historia[2][6] = '2asdfasf';
    $historia[2][3] = '2asdfasf';
    $historia[2][2] = '2asdfasf';
```

and i need to have them sort by the second key, something like this should be the end result:

```
    //person1
    $historia[1][1] = '1asdfasf';
    $historia[8][1] = '1asdfasf';
    $historia[7][1] = '1asdfasf';
    $historia[4][1] = '1asdfasf';

    //person2
    $historia[5][2] = '2asdfasf';
    $historia[6][2] = '2asdfasf';
    $historia[3][2] = '2asdfasf';
    $historia[2][2] = '2asdfasf';
```

and then!

```
    $historia[1][1] = '1asdfasf';
    $historia[2][2] = '2asdfasf';
    $historia[3][2] = '2asdfasf';
    $historia[4][1] = '1asdfasf';
    $historia[5][2] = '2asdfasf';
    $historia[6][2] = '2asdfasf';
    $historia[7][1] = '1asdfasf';
    $historia[8][1] = '1asdfasf';
```

im trying to read some array sorting scripts but im getting verymuch confused so im actually needing external help... could any of you guys give me a lead on this one?

thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: i dont know where to start! :(

Comment: Start with a `for loop` which will go through `$historia[0][1] - $historia[x][0]` adding them to a new array. Then loop through the second "$historia" adding them to the new array. If you're new to loops, start there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$historia[1][1] = '1asdfasf';
$historia[1][8] = '1asdfasf';
$historia[1][7] = '1asdfasf';
$historia[1][4] = '1asdfasf';
$historia[2][5] = '2asdfasf';
$historia[2][6] = '2asdfasf';
$historia[2][3] = '2asdfasf';
$historia[2][2] = '2asdfasf';

$new_array=array();
foreach($historia as $uid=>$sub)
{
    foreach($sub as $hid=>$val)
    {
        if(empty($new_array[$hid])) $new_array[$hid]=array();
        $new_array[$hid][$uid]=$val;
    }
}
ksort($new_array);
print_r($new_array);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1asdfasf
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => 2asdfasf
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [2] => 2asdfasf
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1asdfasf
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [2] => 2asdfasf
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [2] => 2asdfasf
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1asdfasf
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1asdfasf
        )

)
```